# How can I enable PHP errors on OSX Lion?

Tags: php, osx-lion, wsod

I can't get my setup to display PHP errors. The only thing I see is the WSOD.

I've updated my php.ini file:

(excerpt from phpinfo())

```
display_errors          On      On
display_startup_errors  On      On
error_reporting         30719   30719
```

Any ideas?

Comment: *(tip)* set `error_reporting` to `-1` to enable all error levels, current and future.

Comment: I know this does not answer the original question but it might help you out in the mean while: Did you try checking the PHP error log?

Comment: You sure it's not overruled in your script? What happens if you call a simple script like this? `ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); echo $some_fake_var;`. Should throw a: `Notice: Undefined variable: some_fake_var`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using the default installation of Apache in OSX you need to edit `/etc/php.ini` however if you're using a MacPorts install you will need to edit `/opt/local/etc/php5/php.ini`

You state your `phpinfo()` is showing that errors are enabled. If they are not displaying they must be being overridden.

Places to check

- `httpd.conf`, `httpd-vhosts.conf`, and other config files in `/etc/apache2/extras` (not sure on MacPorts paths) - Look for `php_value` lines.
- `.htaccess` files - Again look for `php_value` lines.
- [`.user.ini`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.per-user.php) files - PHP 5.3+ supports per directory configuration like Apache.
- Your scripts themselves. They may implement custom error handlers that turn off
  error reporting with `ini_set`.

You can try enabling at a script level using the following:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', -1);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('html_errors', 1); // I use this because I use xdebug.

0:: // My favourite kind of error.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn error reporting on for a single script with this one liner, Making no permanent changes to config files.

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
```